# Doctrine @OneToMany relation doesn't return Collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

I'm using Symfony 2.7 with Doctrine 2. When using a OneToMany relation, the property remains empty.

### Context

I'm trying to create a filter so that only that only employees that are currently employed at an organisation are able to see the entities related to that organisation. (I've already created a filter with an organisation hard coded, that works).

I've created en Employee entity with a ManyToOne relation to User, a ManyToOne relation to Organisation, a joindate and a leavedate. The user has a (inverse) OneToMany relation to Employee. When I call $user->getEmployees() I get no results.

### Expected result

When calling $user->getEmployees() I expect to get a collection of the three Employee entities that are currently stored in the database with my user_id.

### Actual result

An empty collection is returned, part of the var_dump

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[83]
  private 'snapshot' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'owner' => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[342]
      protected 'id' => int 1
      protected 'groups' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[52]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'owner' => 
            &object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[342]
          private 'association' => 
            array (size=19)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[282]
              ...
          private 'backRefFieldName' => null
          private 'typeClass' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[42]
              ...
          private 'isDirty' => boolean false
          private 'initialized' => boolean false
          private 'coll' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[41]
              ...
      protected 'employees' => 
        &object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[83]
```

### Other info

Searching on Doctrine @OneToMany gives me people that have forgotten some parameters, arguments etc. or made a typo. My college and me cannot find one of those in my code. So I'm kind of stuck. Please Help.

composer.json (part of):

```
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony" : "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm" : "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal" : "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" : "^1.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle" : "1.0.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" : "^2.3"
},
```

Configuration.php (this is the configuration of the filter)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Filter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use AppBundle\Entity\Employee;

class Configurator
{
    protected $em;
    protected $tokenStorage;
    protected $reader;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->em              = $em;
        $this->tokenStorage    = $tokenStorage;
        $this->reader          = $reader;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUser()) {
            $filter = $this->em->getFilters()->enable('organisation');

            $user_id = $user->getId();
            print "User id: $user_id<br />\n"; // Just to check I can get the user_id, that works

            $employeeCollection = $user->getEmployees();  // Get the Employees
            var_dump($employeeCollection); // Oeps, no result
            die(); // Let's just quit (for now)
            // To Do find out all the organisation id's
            // $filter->setParameter('organisation_ids', $organisation_ids);
        }
    }

    private function getUser()
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

        if (!$token) {
            return null;
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!($user instanceof UserInterface)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_group",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Employee", mappedBy="user", cascade="persist")
     */
    protected $employees;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->employees = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function prePersist($user)
    {
        parent::prePersist($user);
        $user->setEmplolyees($user->getEmployees());
    }

    public function preUpdate($user)
    {
        parent::preUpdate($user);
        $user->setEmplolyees($user->getEmployees());
    }

    /**
     * Add employees
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $employee
     * @return Organisation
     */
    public function addEmployee(\AppBundle\Entity\User $employee)
    {
        $employee->setOrganisation($this);
        $this->employees[] = $employee;

        return $this;
    }


    function setEmployees($employees)
    {
        foreach ($employees as $employee)
        {
            $this->addEmployee($employee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove employee
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $employee
     */
    public function removeEmployee(\AppBundle\Entity\User $employee)
    {
        $this->employees->removeElement($employee);
    }

    /**
     * Get employees
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getEmployees()
    {
        return $this->employees;
    }
}
```

Employee.php

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
// use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use AppBundle\Annotation as CRUD;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleted")
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class Employee {


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="employees")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Organisation", inversedBy="employees")
     */
    private $organisation;



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $joindate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $leavedate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     *
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted;




    public function __toString()
    {
       return $this->user . ' - ' . $this->organisation  . ' (' . print_r($this->getJoindate(),1);
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Employee
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set deleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deleted
     * @return Employee
     */
    public function setDeleted($deleted)
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeleted()
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return guid
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Employee
     */
    public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set organisation
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Organisation $organisation
     * @return Employee
     */
    public function setOrganisation(\AppBundle\Entity\Organisation $organisation = null)
    {
        $this->organisation = $organisation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get organisation
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Organisation
     */
    public function getOrganisation()
    {
        return $this->organisation;
    }

    /**
     * Set joindate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $joindate
     * @return Employee
     */
    public function setJoindate($joindate)
    {
        $this->joindate = $joindate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get joindate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getJoindate()
    {
        return $this->joindate;
    }

    /**
     * Set leavedate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $leavedate
     * @return Employee
     */
    public function setleavedate($leavedate)
    {
        $this->leavedate = $leavedate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get leavedate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getleavedate()
    {
        return $this->leavedate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick shot in the dark. Is your employee db table correctly named as 'Employee' (i.e. capitalized)?

Comment: did you check that your user really has employees connected in the database (correctly linked and saved) ... happens sometimes :P ... did you used the auto generator to create the entities and the relations ?

Comment: @technetium How did You implement all these methods in User.php. I mean is this some widely used implementation based on Doctrine documentation or its just your work? I mean it's a lot of work to just get associated Entities. I mean it must be widely needed thing by developers, I can't belive there is no magical alternative to this implementation. What do You think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm doing

```
var_dump(sizeof($employeeCollection));
```

I'm getting the expected result 3.

Lesson learned: The iterator of an colletion is lazy. Do something with it go fill it.

For example:

```
    var_dump(sizeof($employeeCollection));
    var_dump($employeeCollection);
```

Gives the expected result:

```
int 3

object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[85]
  private 'snapshot' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\Employee)[94]
          private 'id' => string '0426c0cc-b517-11e5-8f2e-080027434d34' (length=36)
          private 'user' => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[339]
              ...
          private 'organisation' => 
            object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Organisation)[129]
              ...
          private 'joindate' => 
            object(DateTime)[104]
              ...
          private 'leavedate' => null
          private 'created' => 
            object(DateTime)[96]
              ...
          private 'deleted' => null
      1 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\Employee)[127]
          private 'id' => string '74ca2b62-bac6-11e5-b9ab-080027434d34' (length=36)
          private 'user' => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[339]
              ...
          private 'organisation' => 
            object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Organisation)[122]
              ...
          private 'joindate' => 
            object(DateTime)[125]
              ...
          private 'leavedate' => null
          private 'created' => 
            object(DateTime)[126]
              ...
          private 'deleted' => null
      2 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\Employee)[119]
          private 'id' => string 'c1e45d7f-b53e-11e5-8f2e-080027434d34' (length=36)
          private 'user' => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[339]
              ...
          private 'organisation' => 
            object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Organisation)[118]
              ...
          private 'joindate' => 
            object(DateTime)[130]
              ...
          private 'leavedate' => null
          private 'created' => 
            object(DateTime)[124]
              ...
          private 'deleted' => null
  private 'owner' => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[339]
      protected 'id' => int 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is causing the issue. But it is for sure not helping. In `User` you do:

```
public function addEmployee(\AppBundle\Entity\User $employee)
{
    $employee->setOrganisation($this);
    $this->employees[] = $employee;

    return $this;
}
```

It should be `$employee->setUser($this);`

And another thing. You do:

```
function setEmployees($employees)
{
    foreach ($employees as $employee)
    {
        $this->addEmployee($employee);
    }
}
```

Collections are set using `add` methods, not `set` methods. So you should do:

```
function addEmployees($employees)
{
    foreach ($employees as $employee)
    {
        $this->addEmployee($employee);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I had the impression that the function addEmployee($employee) was to add one employee to the collection and with setEmployees one is able to set the whole collection. I've implemented your suggestions, but still get the same (empty) response.

Comment: Do you get your employees when you do `$entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Employee')->findAll();`

Comment: Yes, var_dump($this->em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Employee')->findAll()); shows all the employees in the database.